# Check input with regex

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a user interface and one input the user has to make is a Point in the format

`(<x-coordinate>,<y-coordinate>)`

I've never worked with Regex before so I am not quite sure how to validate the input. It shouldn't accept it if there is no parenthesis at the beginning or anything else that doesn't match the pattern.

So how can I save the x- and y-coordinate into an integer by removing the other characters and also check if it has the required pattern?

Can someone show me how it's done?

Comment: You can use ```(\d+,\d+)```

Comment: playground to start experimenting with regex https://regex101.com/

Comment: Oh that's nice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your coordinates are integers, you can do a simple regex like this:

```regex
^\((\d+?),(\d+?)\)$
```

That will give you three matching groups. The first for the whole match, the second for the first coordinate, the third for the second coordinate.

You can solve this with Java like this:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Coords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "(123,456)";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\((\\d+?),(\\d+?)\\)$");
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
            int y = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));

            System.out.println("X: " + x);
            System.out.println("Y: " + y);
        }
    }
}
```

Also: A good starting point, when trying out new regular expressions, is here: https://regex101.com/

**EDIT**
If the input should also be parseable, when there is a space after the comma, you can do this:

```regex
^\((\d+?),\s+(\d+?)\)$
```

In Java, the backslashes need to be escaped accordingly.

Comment: Not exactly, \d+ means one or more, + is a greedy operator, so to limit it's range, the ? is appended. But you are right, ? normally means, that the character before is optional. See -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_matching

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the regex pattern:

```
\(\d+,\d+\)
```

Sample script:

```
String input = "(123,456)";
if (input.matches("\\(\\d+,\\d+\\)")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

If you want to extract the two values you could use `String#split`:

```
String input = "(123,456)";
String[] coords = input.substring(1, input.length()-1).split(",");
System.out.println("x = " + coords[0]);
System.out.println("y = " + coords[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I save 123 and 456 as an int?

Comment: Or can't I do that with regex? Do I have to replace all other characters first?

Comment: Oh and what happens if the x-coordinate has a bigger value than int allows? Can I also check that with Regex directly?